# getActionBar() returns null in different languages

Tags: android, localization, android-actionbar

I recently added values-de to my android project. As my mobile is set to german, the correct german resources are being pulled. but since the creation of values-de getActionBar() returns null. In english everything is fine, but in german the actionBar does not seem to be created. also the options menu and everything that comes with it does not work anymore.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: An idea: check whether you've translated all string resources into German.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem myself! I had the styles.xml in values and in values-de! Didnt know that this would be forbidden!

Thanks anyways